# Cuckoo Sandbox on DigitalOcean droplet

Tags: antivirus, droplet, cuckoo

I found a few threads talking about similar problem, running cuckoo sandbox on AWS ec2 for ex. but I'll try to ask anyway.

I currently have a custom PHP solution that just runs file through clamscan but I wanted to use something better.

I have been trying to setup Cuckoo sandbox and use it as virus scan on DigitalOcean droplet but I can't get it working. Is there someone who managed to get it working on ec2 or droplet?

If it help my error is

CRITICAL: CuckooCriticalError: Please update your configuration. Unable to shut 'cuckoo1' down or find the machine in its proper state: The virtual machine 'cuckoo1' doesn't exist! Please create one or more Cuckoo analysis VMs and properly fill out the Cuckoo configuration!

I guess it is VM related (I followed all the docs steps https://cuckoo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/ ).

Answer (score 0):

Checkpoint seems to have got it working
https://research.checkpoint.com/2019/cuckoo-system-on-aws/ .
In their "what's next" section they mention when AWS introduces hibernation for windows, the guest performance can be improved. AWS added this feature in 2019, but i'm not seeing any changes to the git repo for this.
https://github.com/CheckPointSW/Cuckoo-AWS

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).